# Why user data is null in props in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I create multi step register that user create in first step and then send OTP code in last step user set username and password. In last step when I use props show me user is null but in react dev tools user already exist. This Two picture:
[image: In step 3 and there is user in auth]

[image: When I use this.props.auth]

This is my reduser code :

```
    import {
    USER_LOADED,
    USER_LOADING,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL,
    VERIFY_CODE,
    SET_PASS,
    SET_PASS_FAIL,
    VERIFY_FAIL
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    isLoading: false,
    verifyCode : null,
    setPass : null,
    user: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,

            };
        case USER_LOADED:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false,
                verifyCode: true,
                user: action.payload,
            };
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false,
                verifyCode: false
            };
        case SET_PASS_FAIL:
        case AUTH_ERROR:
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
        case VERIFY_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                verifyCode: false,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case VERIFY_CODE :
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload,
                verifyCode: true,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false
            };
        case SET_PASS :
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false,
                setPass: true,
            }
        case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            return {
                token: null,
                user : null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                user: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                isLoading: false,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In last step user fill username and password and we need pass email too. And this my component code :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {loadUser, setPass, verifyCode , browserHistory} from "../../actions/authAction";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {clearError} from "../../actions/errorAction";
import {toast} from "react-toastify";
import store from "../../store";

class RegisterFinal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: this.props.auth,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        store.dispatch(loadUser());
       
    }

    state = {
        user : [],
        userName : "",
        password : "",
        verifyCode : "",
        passwordConfirm : "",
        isLoading: true,
        msg: null
    }

    static propTypes = {
        isAuthenticated : PropTypes.bool,
        setPass : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

        const {error} = this.props;
        if (error !== prevProps.error) {
            if (error.id === 'SET_PASS_FAIL') {
                let status =error.status;
                if (status === 400) {
                    toast.error("کاربر موجود است")
                }
            } else {
                this.setState({msg: null});
            }
        }
    }
    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {password , userName , verifyCode} = this.state
        const setPass = {
            password , userName , verifyCode
        }
        this.props.setPass(setPass);
        const { passwordConfirm } = e.target;
        const errors = {};
        if (password.value !== passwordConfirm.value) {
            errors.passwordMismatch = "Entered passwords do not match.";
            console.log(errors)
        }}
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    render() {
const {user} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className={"container"}>
                <div className={"row row-of-final-register justify-content-center"}>
                    <div className={"mt-5 register-teacher-inputs-box final-register-teacher-inputs-box"}>
                        <div className={"final-register-wrapper"}>
                            <div className={"register-teacher-icon final-register-teacher-icon"}>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div className={"register-teacher-text final-register-teacher-text"}>
                                <h4>
                                   Last Step
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                   Account
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <form className={"mt-5"} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <div className={"row"}>
                                <div className={"col-12"}>
                                    <label
                                        htmlFor={"userName"} className={"text-right username-label"}>
                                        <span>*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control w-100" placeholder={"username"}
                                           name={"userName"}
                                           autoComplete="true"
                                           value={this.userName}
                                           onChange={this.onChange}
                                           onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className={"row"}>
                                <div className={"col-12 col-lg-6 mt-3"}>
                                    <label
                                        htmlFor={"password"} className={" text-right"}>
                                        <span>*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="password" className="form-control " placeholder={"Password"}
                                           name={"password"}
                                           value={this.password}
                                           onChange={this.onChange}
                                           onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div className={"row mt-3 pt-2"}>
                                <div className={"col-12 final-register-wrapper final-register-btn"}>
                                    <button type={"submit"} className={"final-register-btn"}>Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    setPass : state.setPass,
    isAuthenticated : state.isAuthenticated,
    error : state.error,
    auth: state.auth,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps , {
    setPass , clearError ,loadUser
})(RegisterFinal);
```

Comment: Your componentDidMount calls 'loadUser()'

Comment: @Hyetigran actually load data of user from server. is that incorrect?

Comment: You're loading a user in the "Register" component when it first mounts. Could you share loadUser function body? I think if you're going to check if a user exists (maybe via token) and then 'loadUser', it should be done as high up in your Component tree as possible i.e. <App />.

Comment: @SajjadShiasi In the code posted you never set `this.state.user` nor do you ever set it in props with mapStateToProps.

Comment: @Hyetigran Wonderfully I can return all data from user but it's not return in props

Comment: @HMR I try this but still null

Answer (score 0):

```js
// First of all, I would change this, 
// is not a good idea import your store to each component.
import store from '../store';
...
componentDidMount() {
  store.dispatch(loadUser());   
}


// and I would do this
import { loadUser as loadUserAction } from '../actions';
...
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.loadUser();
}
...
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    loadUser: () => dispatch(loadUserAction()),
    setPass: () => dispatch(setPassAction()), 
    clearError: () => dispatch(clearErrorAction()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegisterFinal);
```