# How to access to set redux props to react state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my code and I try to set email of user to state and set it with other data:

```
  import React, {Component} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions/authAction';

import {loadUser, setPass , register} from "../../actions/authAction";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import {clearError} from "../../actions/errorAction";
import {toast} from "react-toastify";
import store from "../../store";


class RegisterFinal extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        store.dispatch(loadUser());

    }
    componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.user !== this.props.user) {
            this.setState({ email: this.props.user});
        }
    }

    state = {
        userName: "",
        password: "",
        passwordConfirm: "",
        email: "",
        msg: null
    }

    static propTypes = {
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
        setPass: PropTypes.bool,
        register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        user : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {password, userName, email} = this.state
        const setPass = {
            password, userName, email
        }
        this.props.setPass(setPass);
        const {passwordConfirm} = e.target;
        const errors = {};
        if (password.value !== passwordConfirm.value) {
            errors.passwordMismatch = "Entered passwords do not match.";
            console.log(errors)
        }
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"container"}>
                <div className={"row row-of-final-register justify-content-center"}>
                    <div className={"mt-5 register-teacher-inputs-box final-register-teacher-inputs-box"}>
                        <div className={"final-register-wrapper"}>
                          
                        <form className={"mt-5"} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <div className={"row"}>
                                <div className={"col-12"}>
                                    <label
                                        htmlFor={"userName"} className={"text-right username-label"}>
                                        <span>*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control w-100" placeholder={"Username"}
                                           name={"userName"}
                                           autoComplete="true"
                                           value={this.userName}
                                           onChange={this.onChange}
                                           onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className={"row"}>
                                <div className={"col-12 col-lg-6 mt-3"}>
                                    <label
                                        htmlFor={"password"} className={" text-right"}>
                                        <span>*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="password" className="form-control " placeholder={"Password"}
                                           name={"password"}
                                           value={this.password}
                                           onChange={this.onChange}
                                  
                                           onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                    />
                                </div>
                
                            </div>
                            <div className={"row mt-3 pt-2"}>
                                <div className={"col-12 final-register-wrapper final-register-btn"}>
                                    <button type={"submit"} className={"final-register-btn"}>Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps (state , ownProperties)  {
    console.log(state.auth.user)
    return {
        setPass: state.auth.setPass,
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
        error: state.error,
        auth: state.auth,
        user : state.auth.user,



    }

};
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps

)(RegisterFinal);
```

When run I have this data in my email state :
[image: display all data from user]

But when I try to access email get Error that cannot read property ‘email’ of undefined, I just change `email : this.props.user` to `email : this.props.user.email` in componentDidUpdate. I actually need to set redux props to react state.  I'm new in redux.
Here share my project : [my project](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-burnell-p4qvr?file=/src/store.js)

Comment: try to check/console nextProps.user or also check as well you if condition is working or not

Comment: Use Constructer or Super in your class component and also try to convert pure function to arrow function, pure function doesn't access Component "this"

Comment: @WaleedNasir After log understand that nextProps.user pass undefined but in react dev tools pass user data. I Set super and user arrow function but give nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why user data is null in props in React Js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516850/why-user-data-is-null-in-props-in-react-js)

Comment: @HMR No, I try to fix that issue and use `componentWillReceiveProps ` then now I have undefined when log from this.props.user.email. Actually  `componentWillReceiveProps ` work but when try to access email of user pass me undefined .

Comment: @SajjadShiasi You asked the same question 4 times without ever updating existing questions. The one time I asked a question (your code didn't make sense and could never have worked because you were not setting anything) you replied with "I tried it doesn't work" you should know as a programmer that such a response does not help. If you tried something it would be helpful if update your question with what you tried and show what doesn't work. Just reposting your question with your current code is not the best way to get a solution.

Comment: @HMR You're right. at the first I don't know what is problem search  many time and find that redux props is asynchronous then I change my code and use `componentWillReceiveProps  `. Now when log `componentWillReceiveProps  ` I have user data but I have not access to them.

Comment: @SajjadShiasi Added an answer, used `initial` in this.state to check if the inital value was set from state and use loading. Hope it helps. You can change the code to your specifications (fake api) and post it as a snippet if you still have trouble getting it to work.

Comment: @HMR Thank you. I try This and if have error update my question

Comment: @HMR Where I use action thunks? I'm little confused

Comment: @SajjadShiasi I guessed `store.dispatch(loadUser());` is a thunk action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example that will async load a user, set the initial value of a textbox with it's value and submit changes:

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  loading: true, //initially set loading to true
};
//helper for async
const later = (value) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 2000)
  );
//action types
const CHANGE_USER = 'CHANGE_USER';
const CHANGED_USER = 'CHANGED_USER';
const LOAD_USER = 'LOAD_USER';
const LOADED_USER = 'LOADED_USER';
//action creators
const loadUser = () => ({
  type: LOAD_USER,
});
const loadedUser = (user) => ({
  type: LOADED_USER,
  payload: user,
});
const changeUser = () => ({
  type: CHANGE_USER,
});
const changedUser = (user) => ({
  type: CHANGED_USER,
  payload: user,
});
// action thunks
const loadUserThunk = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loadUser());
  return later({
    email: 'original-email',
  }).then((user) => dispatch(loadedUser(user)));
};
const changeUserThunk = (email) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(changeUser());
  return later({
    email,
  }).then((user) => dispatch(changedUser(user)));
};
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === LOAD_USER || type === CHANGE_USER) {
    return { ...state, loading: true };
  }
  if (type === LOADED_USER || type === CHANGED_USER) {
    return {
      ...state,
      user: payload,
      loading: false,
    };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectUser = (state) => state.user;
const selectLoading = (state) => state.loading;
const selectUserEmail = createSelector(
  [selectUser],
  //want to use user?.email but SO babel is too old
  (user) => user && user.email
);
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      ({ getState, dispatch }) =>
        (next) =>
        (
          action //simple thunk implementation
        ) =>
          typeof action === 'function'
            ? action(dispatch, getState)
            : next(action)
    )
  )
);
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    email: '',
    initial: true, //only initially set from redux
  };
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.props.loading && this.state.initial) {
      this.setState({
        email: this.props.email,
        initial: false,
      });
    }
  }
  //arrow function so you don't need to bind for "this" context
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(changeUserThunk(this.state.email));
    //reset initial
    this.setState({ initial: true });
  };
  emailChanged = (e) =>
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadUserThunk());
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.emailChanged}
          value={this.state.email}
          // do not edit when loading
          disabled={this.props.loading}
        />
        <input type="submit" />
        {this.props.loading && 'loading...'}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
//do not use store in your components, connect will provide
//  dispatch on this.props when mapDispatchToProps is
//  undefined  or you can pass an object as mapDispatchToProps
const ConnectedApp = connect((state) => ({
  email: selectUserEmail(state), //select state.user.email as props.email
  loading: selectLoading(state),
}))(App);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```